# rooting galaxy s4 GT-I9505 with android 4.4.2 kitkat

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I tried to root phone according to [instruction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTUmrLnu6XY).

And it was ok. It seemed that my phone successfully rooted.

But when I run [root checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck) it showed that I don't have root access.

Comment: Flash super SU zip in recovery. Open the app and update the binaries. Then try root checker again. Have you super su installed, can you open it and update the binaries? Root checker needs to be granted super user access somehow, that's done via superSU

Answer (score 1):

Easy way: Wipe your phone and try again from fresh stock.

- but only do this if in [adb shell] you can execute "su" successfully.